# "forge run web" does not find node.js

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I began working through the Trigger.io tutorial. After viewing the output successfully in the iPhone simulator and the Android emulator, I decided I wanted to see it in a desktop browser, so ran `forge run web` as [per the docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/web/index.html). However, this didn't work: the command apparently could not find Node.js, even though it is installed, up to date, and on my path.

```
(forge-environment)spksmb:demo-app sampablokuper$ forge run web
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.0
[   INFO] enabled platforms: ['web']
[   INFO] <ForgeTask (web)> running...
[   INFO] reading app code from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/Documents/demo-app/src
[   INFO] writing new app to /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/Documents/demo-app/development
[   INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[   INFO] JavaScript check complete
[   INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[   INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[  ERROR] failed to run npm: do you have Node.js installed and on your path? while running run_web((), {})
[  ERROR] failed to run npm: do you have Node.js installed and on your path?
(forge-environment)spksmb:demo-app sampablokuper$ which node
/opt/local/bin/node
(forge-environment)spksmb:demo-app sampablokuper$ node -v
v0.6.15
```

Is this a bug, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually `npm` we're trying to run here; of course, if `node` is on your path I'd expect `npm` to be there too, but would be worth checking it's there and can be executed:

```
which npm
npm -v
npm ls
```

If `npm` really is on your path, send your `forge-error.log` file to support@trigger.io and we'll have a look through it.

Comment: Aha! After I initially encountered the error, I installed Node.js via MacPorts: `sudo port install nodejs`. Having done this, Node.js was indeed installed and on my path. However, installing Node.js in this way doesn't install npm. For that, I have now run `sudo port install npm`, and `forge run web` is now working. Might be an idea to make your error message clearer for people who haven't used Node.js or npm before, e.g. "do you have npm (the Node.js package manager) installed and on your path?" Anyhow: thanks, James!